# Optimistic locking in aerospike java

Tags: java, aerospike

I was looking at example where one can take lock of a row in aerospike.
Documents mentioned below says that it has support but can't find example form same.Can anybody please share method(s) which support these

Reference:
https://docs.aerospike.com/display/V3/Key-Value+Store

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this by setting the appropriate attributes in the WritePolicy. For example, for our Java client, you can check the details here:

http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/policy/WritePolicy.html

You want to look at GenerationPolicy:

http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/policy/GenerationPolicy.html

Also note that our documentation has been updated and is now under http://www.aerospike.com/docs

Comment: Hi Meher, I'm looking for this functionality as well and it seems unclear from the documentation that you pointed to how one would use GenerationPolicy to get a row lock. Can you explain this further, possibly showing some code?

Comment: Here are a bit of details for the java client: http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/java/usage/kvs/write.html#read-modify-write basically you read the record, and then when you write it back you have to set the write policy to EXPECT_GEN_EQUAL. The write transaction would fail if the generation has changed since the read.

Comment: Meher, thanks that's very much what I was looking for. Unfortunately, that was somehow impossible to find between myself and a colleague and we ended up writing our own solution using a bin to do the row locking ourselves. As you can imagine this isn't pretty. 
Do you happen to be associated with Aerospike? If you are I would suggest calling that out more prominently within the docs.

Comment: Yes, I do work at Aerospike. Thanks for the feedback!